# Custom Spring JPA query to fetch a Map

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an entity with a `Map<String,string>` of `specifications`:

```
class Product {
    Map<String, String> specifications;
}
```

I have to create a custom query with 2 parameters (key, value) that will fetch all products where specifications with key equals some value.

For example, fetch products with color red (pseudo code):

> loop through products;
>  fetch product;
>  join specifications;
>   get value by key 'color' and compare it to given value 'red'; add to output if true;
>   next product;

I tried this query:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Products p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.specifications, p.reviews WHERE p.specifications.?1 = ?2")
```

But obviously, it doesn't work.

Comment: "it didn't work". "obviously". You're really telling us a lot there. "d.specifications.?1" is clearly invalid JPQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One working solution is as below :

```
SELECT p FROM Product p LEFT JOIN p.specifications, p.reviews m
where ( KEY(m) = :1 and :2 in (VALUE(m)) )
```